# Is it allowed to name the parameter in postfix operator ++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am not using this code in any production environment, it is just for my understanding. Is this code valid (i.e. can I define my postfix operator like this?):

```
class A
{
public:
    A& operator++(int n)
    {
        std::cout<<"N is:"<<n<<"\n";
        return *this;
    }
};


int main()
{   
    A a;
    a++;
    a.operator ++(10);
}
```

On VS2008, I get the output as:

> N is 0

for first call and

> N is 10

for second call

Comment: i didn't even know that was allowed...wild.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This behavior is legal and well defined in 13.5.7:

> Calling operator++ explicitly, as in
>   expressions like a.operator++(2), has
>   no special properties: The argument to
>   operator++ is 2.

Answer (score 11):

`a++` is equivalent to `a.operator++(0);`. Your code is valid

13.5/7

> When the postfix increment is called as a result of using the ++ operator, the int
>     argument will have value zero.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is valid the int as a parameter it only a policy enforcing parameter to distinguish between prefix and postfix operators. The passed parameter will be received as an argument, which is the behavior you see & it is prfectly defined behavior.