# Overloading post increment operator results in argument valued at 0

Tags: c++, post-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it allowed to name the parameter in postfix operator ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094732/is-it-allowed-to-name-the-parameter-in-postfix-operator)

I created an object to hold a list of objects that maintains the current position internally, so I thought this was a great place to overload the pre and post increment operators, which effectively increment this internal position with bounds checking.

What I noticed is, when you call `++` on the object, the argument is `0`.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A {
public:
   A& operator++(int n) { printf("%d  ", n); return *this; }
};
int main() {
   A a;
   a++;
   a.operator++(0);
   a.operator++(1);
   a.operator++(10);
   return 0;
}
```

This returns `0 0 1 10`. From what I understand, this is normal behavior. So, it has made me rethink how `operator++` should work. Previously, I was simply calling `++` on my internal position variable if bounds checking passed. But this has the affect of incrementing by 1 no matter what the input argument is. Next, I though of using the `+=` using the argument `n` as the right hand side, but as you'll notice, simply calling `++` with no operators (as is customary), gives a zero and the position is **not** incremented.

Basically, is this something I should even worry about? If so, how do I detect if the user really wanted 0, or if the default behavior (`a++`) was intended and I should increment by 1?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094732/

Comment: Really funny that there two questions about this in one day.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: duplicate, actually.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Hilarious! Some smart ass at work used the operator directly like that to prove a point, so now I am trying to prove one back by making the code handle it.

Comment: I wonder is he saw that question and decided to be funny.

Comment: Do not abuse it. The ++ operator should only be used to increment the object by one increment. i.e. it should have the affect of += 1. If you abuse the operator it will just confuse people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just ignore the parameter.

Comment: So, `a.operator++(10);` is not technically a valid thing to do then, even though it works?

Comment: It is totally valid to do, but in any sensible implementation it will have no effect. And noone should write code that relies on such behavior. It is asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The int in the operator is put there or not by the compiler. It indicates whether you have the prefix or sufix operator. (++a a++)